# Routing IP packets from one IP addr to another

Tags: linux, networking, routes

Can somebody tell me what are the ways of routing packets in a linux system. I have an external and internal network interfaces on my linux system. I want to forward packets arriving at my external network to an internal network.

I do not have iptables. What are the other ways to this? What commands are offered by native linux. Should Netfilter always be enabled for this? My kernel does not come with Netfilter.

So please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about *real* routing, and not any form of Network Address Translation (NAT), you just need to enable IP forwarding, and put the relevant routes in your routing table:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Configuring NAT does require iptables.

Comment: Yes, I did enable ip_forward but how to enable IP addr A to be forwarded to IP addr B? will a simple route add command forward packets on interface A at IP addr A to interface B at IP addr B?

Comment: Just set your routing table as required. 'route add A gw B' basically.

Comment: Hi Kristof, the idea is only A is the visible IP addr to the external devices. So if I send packets to A at port XX then they should be automatically routed to IP addr B at port XX by System A.